# Uploading a file using the src-adress

Tags: javascript, ajax, blob

I've created an audio recorder in javascript. After recording the js append an audio tag to my html. I get something like that:

```
<audio controls="" src="blob:http://localhost/7f76fcb8" data-id="7"></audio>
```

My goal is to take the File and pass it through an ajax to an PHP File to save it on the server. What is the best way to achieve this goal ?

Comment: I never tried that, but my first idea would be trying to do an ajax-connect to that url, read the contents and post it to the server. It seems that the recorded audio data is hosted within the browser itself. No idea if you can connect there.